# Two arrays of size 200 and 300. How do you concatenate the array to make it 200x300?

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, jupyter

I have two arrays of size 200 and 300. However I would like to merge them to be an array of 200x300 so 200 rows and 300 columns. This is a basic question I know... and not even sure it's possible but how might I do this?

I tried using np.hstack but hstack created an array of size 500:

```
array1 = np.random.rand(200)
array2 = np.random.rand(300)

test = np.hstack((array1,array2))
test.shape
(500,)
```

I also tried stack, vstack, block, etc. but they require that the arrays are the same length, however with the real data I am using the arrays are not the same length.

My goal is to make one 2d array with shape 200x300.

Comment: An array with shape (200,300) has 60000 *items*. `array1` and `array2` have 500 *items* between them. How do you want to fill all those other items? Your [mre] should use arrays with smaller dimensions and should include an expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
a = np.random.rand(2)
b = np.random.rand(3)

np.outer(a, b)

array([[0.10570007, 0.14838246, 0.04037839],
       [0.13164818, 0.18480859, 0.0502908 ]])
```